# Implementing both vertical and horizontal pagination (almost like a grid)?

Tags: android

I'm new to android development, and I need to figure out a way to implement two sets of fragments, as shown here:

[image]

The idea is that you have a set of fragments in the upper row, such as musical artists, and then clicking on a particular artist moves that fragment upward to show a new set of fragments that represent albums corresponding to the selected artist. You can then scroll through the albums, and if you press back, the artist fragment moves back down into the view and you can scroll to a new artist horizontally again. I've tried a couple of different things:

- using a view animator and having both view pagers in the view animator. Unfortunately I couldn't figure out how to make it so that once the animation finished, the appearance of the layout would remain (ie with the artist fragment poking through the top)
- having two distinct activities and trying an activity animation, but again, couldn't make it so that the top fragment still showed on the screen
- having a vertical viewpager, with two fragments that each contain a horizontal viewpager. This seems like it could potentially work, but I think having nested viewpagers is discouraged/not a good idea, and I started to implement it but the code became such a mess that I was hoping there was something else I could try instead.

Comment: I think you want a viewpager in a vertical viewpager where each row is dependant on what the row above it has for a selection.